# Rank of group on exact sequence

Tags: group-theory

As all of us know for each abelian group , denote $TA$ is group of all finite order element in $A$ then $A / TA$ is a free abelian group in case $A$ is finite generated . Rank of $A / TA$ is called rank of $A$ . Assume I have an exact sequence :

$$ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$

I want to prove $\mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(C)$ without using linearly independent basis . I try to prove the following sequence is exact :

$$0 \to A / TA \to B / TB \to C / TC \to 0$$

Then because $C/TC$ is free abelian , the sequence is split exact . But I can't verify why the new sequence above is still exact ? Here I assume $A,B,C$ is finite generated

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer given was deleted, but I don't know proof of this which doesn't use either basis of the groups involved or flatness of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and tensoring over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ . I'm not saying there is no other kind of proof, just that I don't know it and if it exists then perhaps it won't be easy to come up with it...

Comment: Sorry , $A / TA$ is free abelian in the case $A$ is finite generated